# running utf8 encoded php script with fastcgi

Tags: php, cgi, fastcgi

I have installed Nginx and I used fastcgi to run php script.

When I run php script encoded as "utf8" I have got an error about "header":

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /xxx/myScript.php:1) in /xxx/myScript.php on line 29....

If I encode the same script in "ascii", I have not this error.

I have a lot of scripts and some of them are in utf8.

Does anybody know how to run utf8 script with fastcgi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your editor to store UTF-8 files without BOM. Open your file in an hexeditor to see the BOM to confirm, as in normal editors you won't see it.